# Hack Legend Key for Lollipop Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to replace the element of a column with the element of another column in `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- read.table(text =
                    "nbb_RMSE  9 0.2402482
                     mbb_RMSE  9 0.1023012
                     cbb_RMSE  8 0.2031448
                     tmbb_RMSE 4 0.2654746
                     tcbb_RMSE 9 0.4048711")

colnames(df1) <- c("Methods", "lb", "RMSE")

df1 |>
  mutate(colour = fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Here is its output]

**What I Want**

The `lb` column should be arranged as follows: `Green` which represents the smallest `RMSE` corresponds to 9 in `lb` column, `yellowgreen` which represent the nest high value in `RMSE` corresponds to 8 in `lb` column,`yellow` which represent the nest high value in `RMSE` corresponds to 9 in `lb` column, `orange` which represent the nest high value in `RMSE` corresponds to 4 in `lb` column,`red` which represent the nest high value in `RMSE` corresponds to 9 in `lb` column.

I want the label `color` on the legend to change to the name of a column called `lb` in the dataframe.

Here is [image: what I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `name` and `labels` arguments in `scale_color_manual`

```r
df1 |>
  mutate(colour = fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", 
                                "orange", "red"),
                     labels = c(9, 8, 9, 9, 4), name = "lb") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]